# Как исправить RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python

```
def f(n):
    if n==1: return n
    if n>1:return  n*f(n-1)
print (f(2023)/f(2020))
```

питон выдает это:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zver\Desktop\Егэ инф\162.py", line 4, in <module>
    print (f(2023)/f(2020))
  File "C:\Users\Zver\Desktop\Егэ инф\162.py", line 3, in f
    if n>1:return  n*f(n-1)
  File "C:\Users\Zver\Desktop\Егэ инф\162.py", line 3, in f
    if n>1:return  n*f(n-1)
  File "C:\Users\Zver\Desktop\Егэ инф\162.py", line 3, in f
    if n>1:return  n*f(n-1)
  [Previous line repeated 1021 more times]
  File "C:\Users\Zver\Desktop\Егэ инф\162.py", line 2, in f
    if n==1: return n
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
>>>
```

Comment: слишком большая глубина рекурсии

Comment: по умолчанию максимальная глубина выставлена в 1000 - у тебя больше 2000 - вот и ошибка. Проверь на числах меньше 1000

Comment: `print(2021*2022*2023)`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, возможно тут цель не в получении значения, а в понимании работы рекурсии

Comment: А факториал _действительно_ нужно вычислять при помощи рекурсии для таких значений?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно изменить подход

Во-первых, для вычисления факториала рекурсия не нужна, достаточно простого цикла

Во-вторых, если факториал ещё понадобится, он есть в `math`

В третьих, задачу `print (f(2023)/f(2020))` несравненно более эффективно решать, обдумав математику:

```
 res = 1
 for i in range(2021, 2024):
    res *= i
 print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
def f(n):
    if n==1: return n
    if n>1:return  n*f(n-1)
print (f(2023)/f(2020))
```

Вот так можно расширить глубину рекурсии